# unable to see EJB under Universal Test Client

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6, rad

I want to test my @Stateless Ejb that I've deployed under WAS 7,
with Universal Test Client within RAD

I'm unable however to find my ejb inside the UTC Exlporer JNDI tree

My ejb-jar.xml cointains:

```
<ejb-name>MyEjb</ejb-name>
    <home>com.ibm.websphere.scheduler.TaskHandlerHome</home>
    <remote>com.ibm.websphere.scheduler.TaskHandler</remote>
    <ejb-class>ejb.MyEjb</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
```

Comment: At the risk of asking a dumb question, is it in `java:comp/env/ejb/MyEjb`?